# How to Add plugin for Xcode 6+

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcode6, xcode6.1

Adding plugin for Xcode 6

Open your terminal and type this without quotes.
"cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns"

or

same in terminal type this without quotes.
"open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns"

Copy/Add/Drag&Drop your plugins there. 
Note: This will require an authentication for administrator password. Authenticate, it is safe. lol

for Plugins Removal:

just do the same, go to the said path and reverse the process.... "Move to Trash".

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for this.

I'm adding a complementary action that made the plugin work for me on Xcode 6.1.1 :

1. Right click on plugin file > **Show Package Contents**
2. Find and edit the **Info.plist** file.
3. In **DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs** add the key C4A681B0-4A26-480E-93EC-1218098B9AA0

Save your Info.plist file.

Then launch Xcode and use your plugins